# I can't access my apollo server through a proxy

Tags: proxy, graphql, apollo-server, snowpack

I've set up [apollo server](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/) on port 3000 on local host and it works fine. I can use the playground and make queries and they all work. ( some text pixilated for privacy )

[image]

However my front end is a Svelte application being served from port 8080 on localhost via [snowpack](https://www.snowpack.dev/). I've setup the snowpack config to proxy localhost:8080/api to localhost:3000

```
  proxy: {
    "/api": "http://localhost:3000/"
  },
```

If I try to access the playground via http://localhost:8080/api then the web UI appears but there seem to be errors with the graphql protocol. The UI complains that `the server cannot be reached`

[image]

If I enter developer mode I see the following request failing

```
POST /api HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1468
accept: */*
Apollo-Query-Plan-Experimental: 1
X-Apollo-Tracing: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
content-type: application/json
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: http://localhost:8080/api/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-AU,en;q=0.9,de-AT;q=0.8,de;q=0.7,en-GB;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.5
```

with request body
[image]

The response given back is

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
connection: close
Date: Thu, 12 Nov 2020 18:40:59 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Does something need to be configured with the server to allow it to work through a proxy like this?